# PHP Break Line Character For Function Arguments

Tags: coda, code-folding

I have this code :

```
public function registerNew ($first_name, $last_name, $email, $phone, $password, $bank_name, $bank_account_number, $bank_account_name, $gender, $birthday, $address, $area, $signup_date, $activated, $first_login, $token, $referred_by, $referral_id, $default_type) {

//some code here

}
```

and I want to make it pretty like this :

```
public function registerNew ($first_name, $last_name, $email, $phone, $password,
                             $bank_name, $bank_account_number, $bank_account_name,
                             $gender, $birthday, $address, $area, $signup_date,
                             $activated, $first_login, $token, $referred_by,
                             $referral_id, $default_type) {

//some code here

}
```

but, since I just hit enter button at the end of the line, then every time I tried to fold this function, my code editor fold everything until only the class name appears like this :

```
class User {...}
```

I'm expecting an output like this :

```
class User {

public function registerNew ($first_name, $last_name, $email, $phone, $password,
                                     $bank_name, $bank_account_number, $bank_account_name,
                                     $gender, $birthday, $address, $area, $signup_date,
                                     $activated, $first_login, $token, $referred_by,
                                     $referral_id, $default_type) {...}
}
```

do I have to put some character to break the lines instead of just hit enter button? or this just my code editor's problem?

thank you

Comment: It definitely is you code editors problem. It is the only thing involved in code folding.

Comment: what is the code editor?

Comment: @ChrisBanks : I'm using Coda 2.5 (Mac)

Comment: @RobertHanson, I'm not able to duplicate this. When I add all the code you have and try to fold the `registerNew` function, it folds that way you indicated that you expected.